# Used MacBook Pro being administrator by previous user

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I recently picked up a used MacBook Pro and after resetting it and installing a fresh version of the OS I am being told it is in remote recovery mode and I am not even allowed to boot from another disk. Everywhere I search about this the verdict comes up it must be stolen. I highly doubt that because if I never wiped it clean I did not see these messages. Someone else is in-charge of my Mac as a security admin and I can not move forward. Should I call Apple? Should I just take the loss? All I want to do is have complete control over my own purchase and not some admin out there taking over my machine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is a remnant either of the previous owner's security settings, or remote management installed by the previous owner's employment or school. Only that previous owner, employer, or school can remove it. If you can return it to the seller, you should do so.

Comment: Oh ok, so it was set up by a employer or a school and that is that? UGH! I doubt I can return it but will try to do so since otherwise it is unusable!!!